# How to Calculate the Coordinates of touch in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, touch

I want show a popup at touch Coordinates. I am using Stack and Positioned widgets to place the popup.

Comment: I have added an answer to your question about showing popups after a touch event, I would suggest you make your post clearer because it is a bit confusing now, the title and the body are unclear and do not seem to relate with each other.

Comment: @aziza I want to show an popup at those coordinates where the screen is touched .

Comment: @aziza for Example if  screen is graph then  if I touch at (15,15)point then pop should show at  (15,15)....

Comment: I still do not understand your question, what does it mean for a pop to show at a specific point? Can you show us some code of your work so we can understand better ?

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand your question at first, I have removed my answer and I think aptik answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add a [GestureDetector](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) as parent of stack, and register `onTapDownDetails` listener. This should call your listener on every tapdown event, with global offset of the tap in [TapDownDetails](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/gestures/TapDownDetails-class.html) parameter of the your listener.

Here is sample code demonstrating the same.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Popup Demo'),
        ),
        body: new MyWidget());
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new MyWidgetState();
  }
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  double posx = 100.0;
  double posy = 100.0;

  void onTapDown(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details) {
    print('${details.globalPosition}');
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    setState(() {
      posx = localOffset.dx;
      posy = localOffset.dy;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => onTapDown(context, details),
      child: new Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: <Widget>[
        // Hack to expand stack to fill all the space. There must be a better
        // way to do it.
        new Container(color: Colors.white),
        new Positioned(
          child: new Text('hello'),
          left: posx,
          top: posy,
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking at all the options on GestureDetector() but can't find anything that helps me know when the user releases a slider widget.  Is there a more generic way to know if the touch of the screen is still active?

Comment: @Eradicatore What about onTapUp property at the GestureDetector documentation page? 
"A pointer that will trigger a tap with a primary button has stopped contacting the screen at a particular location". https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector/onTapUp.html Or https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/PointerDownEvent-class.html

Comment: What do I have to do to get x, y position for Alignment(x,y)

Comment: ```The method 'globalToLocal' isn't defined for the type 'RenderObject'.```

Comment: Isn't even the line before an issue? `A value of type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'RenderBox'.`

Comment: @bluenote10, I think this is due to null safety stata of dart, just add the ? and you'll be good!

Comment: How is this answer accepted when the code throws compilation errors?

Comment: It would have compiled back then, but now we need to type this...
    final RenderObject? box = context.findRenderObject();
    if (box is RenderBox) {
      final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use a `Listener` as the parent of your `Stack` and listen to it's `onPointerDown` event like so:

```dart
Listener(
  onPointerDown: (event) {
    // use event.localPosition.dx or event.localPosition.dy
  },
  child: Stack(
    children: [

    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: better to use on onPointerMove if you want to have continuous value