# Retrieving typing input/coordinate information from keyboard

Tags: flutter

Im trying to retrieve typing information such as the on-screen coordinates of where a user presses a key on a keyboard on Android and iOS using flutter similar to how swiftkey does it to generate their [heatmaps.](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://d3vvnhml5anv1n.cloudfront.net/content/uploads/2014/09/Heat_Map.png&imgrefurl=https://blog.swiftkey.com/access-swiftkey-heatmap/&h=1978&w=1152&tbnid=k3UnvGjoqKt1iM&q=swiftkey+heatmap&tbnh=150&tbnw=87&usg=AI4_-kTHeuQxI20PwE0nDdD9X0L-RIz4Sw&vet=1&docid=gGlFiFequjMpeM&itg=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmi7jj8Y7iAhUi63MBHUs9CTcQ_h0wC3oECAsQBA)

How would I go about doing this? Do I have to create my own custom keyboard

I've tried to implement the suggestion here: [How to Calculate the Coordinates of touch in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560982/how-to-calculate-the-coordinates-of-touch-in-flutter)

But once the keyboard drawer pops up, the on-screen coordinates do not register.

Comment: Yes, you will have to build your own keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you would have to show your own keyboard that you build in flutter. The reason for this is that the keyboard which pops up is actually a different android window (or at least activity, but pretty sure window and likely process as well), that is shown over top of the window that flutter is rendering into. By design, the keypresses can't be recorded as that would be a security issue (the active app is one thing, but imagine if another app could record keypresses or even location of taps - they could steal your passwords!).

There may be some android-specific way of doing it that I'm not aware of, but it probably won't work on all devices and all keyboards and is likely not a good route to follow.