# Flutter: Show where user clicked

Tags: animation, flutter, onclick, gesturedetector, flare

Is it possible to show an animation where the user clicked on the screen in flutter. I would like a small animated star to appear right where the user pressed on the screen.

I have this animation which for the moments just loops but i only want it to loop while the user presses the screen.

```
 new Container(
  alignment: Alignment(0.0, -1.0),

    child: new Container(
     height: 410.0,

            child: FlareActor(
              "assets/images/nyastar.flr",

             animation: _animationName,
            )
    )
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46566392/5882307

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => new MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<Demo> {
  double posx = 100.0;
  double posy = 100.0;

  void onTapDown(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details) {
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    setState(() {
      posx = localOffset.dx;
      posy = localOffset.dy;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => onTapDown(context, details),
      child: new Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: <Widget>[
        // Hack to expand stack to fill all the space. There must be a better
        // way to do it.
        new Container(color: Colors.white),
        new Positioned(
          child: Text('hello'), //your widget to be shown
          left: posx,
          top: posy,
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do i make it work when someone drag their finger on the screen as well (it should start a new animation everywhere they touch so that it could make a trail)? and to only work att the top half of the screen so that i still can press on other buttons?