# How to put gesture detector at specific points on the photo?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I will make an application with Flutter. I want to show different pop-ups when I click on certain parts of a photo that I imported from outside in the application.

For example, get a photo like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPLvv.png)

When I click on the fields I have determined in this photo, I want to give a pop-up according to the field and give information.

one more example.
[image]

I want to show what the button does by opening a pop-up when you put this png into practice and click on the fields I specified.
Do you have any suggestions for a resource or library that I can mark on the photo or help me?[!

Comment: create Stack and put some sized gesture detector over this image

Comment: @Bunny1376 Yes that seems to make sense. Thank you for your answer, I will try, but I do not know how the response will look for designs.

Comment: Another thing you could try is use a GestureDetector and find out from the coordinates, where your image has been tapped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560982/how-to-calculate-the-coordinates-of-touch-in-flutter#answer-46566392