# How can i get the height of any point on screen by touching on it

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to determine any point height on screen by touching  on it.

here is screenshot

[image]

Note: the black point is not widget , i just made it toc explain , i want to determine the height of any point where the finger touch

How could i actives this ?

Comment: points don't have dimensions - they are described by `Offset` class and its `dx` and `dy` properties

Comment: so does there a way to determine the Offset on where finger has touch ?

Answer (score 1):

i found good answer by @pskink

All what we need is to wrap out widget into `GestureDetector` and use `onPanStart` property

```
onPanStart: (d) => log(d.localPosition.toString()),
```

thanks for wonderful person @pskink

Answer (score 0):

you might want to take a look here: [How to Calculate the Coordinates of touch in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560982/how-to-calculate-the-coordinates-of-touch-in-flutter) seems like the issue you are having is solved here